# How do I populate a UITableView that is a subview of a subview?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uikit

My app features a UIWindow (inside of the AppDelegate?).  Amazingly, (by mostly good luck), I've managed to get a NIB file to display inside of my AppDelegate's UIWindow.  The resulting user interface which is displayed from my NIB file is comprised of three controls:

- a UIView which serves as a sort of "background" (called "MainView")
- a UITextView on top of MainView
- a UITableView, also onto top of MainView, located geographically below the UITextView

I've spent the last month trying to populate that Table.  Now I'm asking here.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a UITableViewController subclass, then you need to set it as the datasource and delegate of the tableView, once there you just need to fill out the appropriate methods.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;   
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take a look at Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Specifically, take a look at the prerequisites section (delegate objects, and Model-View-Controller).

Once you have a basic understanding of how view controllers and delegation work, look at (and implement) the [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocols. The basic way to do this is to create a UITableViewController class - XCode has a template for this class with stubbed methods.